# Does a one-to-one function exhibit "injectiveness" or "injectivity"?

Tags: functions, terminology

I'm preparing some tutorials for students and I'm faced with writer's block. If I want to say a function is injective/one-to-one, would the function demonstrate "injectivity" or "injectiveness"? Similarly, what is the convention used for surjective/bijective functions?

Comment: I've never heard of "injectiveness" before. "Injectivity" is usually what I see.

Comment: [Injectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#I)

Comment: If you just reword your sentences I'm sure that you could avoid ever having to use these words

Comment: @TylerHG I know, but I'm breaking up the tutorial into sections. This one is about properties of functions, and for the sake of being succinct I'd like to use one word for the heading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither "injectivity" nor "injectiveness" have made it to the Oxford English Dictionary.  A MathSciNet search for titles containing "injectivity" yields 702 hits, but "injectiveness" just 7.  So I'd say "injectivity" is the clear winner.

Answer (score 2):

"Injectivity" is usually what I see.

Answer (score 0):

Injectivity is derived more in Latin. In French, injectivité is widely used. I wonder how to say "there is an injection from A to B" as easily as in French : "A s'injecte à B".

Invectiveness sounds more Anglo-Saxon, but we rarely see its usage. So we can suppose the employment of such idea is not really English ....